# Буферизация данных в С

Tags: c++, c

Всем привет. Интересует следующий вопрос. Ввод/вывод на стандартные потоки в С (stdin/stdout) буферизированный, это означает, что вся информация которая поступает на эти потоки накапливается в буфере и потом записывается в файл (консоль). Прочитал, что запись происходит, когда буфер заполняется полностью. Какой размер буфера? Думаю, размер колеблется в районе пару килобайт, но тогда почему если, например, идет функция printf() и за ней scanf(), то на экран выводится то, что передается в printf(), вывод же буферизированный и буфер не заполнился полностью или есть еще моменты когда содержимое из буфера записывается в файл? К этому так же не могу понять зачем нужен fflash(). Объясните, пожалуйста, простым языком. Спасибо

Comment: Если stdout идет в терминал (функция [isatty()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)), то flush делается по '\n' / fflush нужен для ручного управления скидыванием буфера. Например, перед [fork()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Стандарт Си определяет три вида буферизации потоков<sup>¹</sup>:

- *Небуферизированные* потоки (*unbuffered*) — буферизации на стороне программы/libc как таковой нет: все данные по возможности сразу передаются ОС/устройству.
- *Полностью буферизированные* (*fully buffered*) — данные записываются в буфер и будут фактически выведены только при его заполнении или при его принудительном сбросе.
- *Линейно-буферизированные* (*line buffered*) — данные буферизируются, но выводятся, если в потоке встретится символ конца строки (`\n`), если буфер будет полностью заполнен или принудительно сброшен. Также все *линейно-буферизированные* потоки вывода (в частности `stdout`) сбрасываются, когда какой-либо (обычно другой, например, `stdin`) *линейно-буферизированный* поток пытается что-либо прочитать, а его буфер ввода пуст.

Для стандартных потоков также гарантируется:

- `stderr` не является *полностью буферизированным*. На практике почти во всех реализациях он будет небуферезированным.
- `stdin` и `stdout` могут быть полностью буферизированными только если они **не** указывают на интерактивное устройство (т.е. ввод/вывод перенаправлен в файл, а не ведётся с консоли/терминала). Почти на всех POSIX-системах они линейно-буферизированyые. Но реализация стандартной библиотеки в msvc не поддерживает линейно-буферизированные потоки, так что там они небуферизированные.

Поменять тип буферизации и задать свой буфер можно с помощью [`setvbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf).

---

> Какой размер буфера?

Зависит от реализации, он доступен в макросе `BUFSIZ`. Размер гарантированно больше 256, типовые значения: 512—8k. Но внутренняя структура и алгоритм работы этого буфера не специализированы, так что это не значит, что в/из файла будут читаться/писаться именно столько байтов.

> тогда почему если, например, идет функция printf() и за ней scanf(), то на экран выводится то, что передается в printf(), вывод же буферизированный и буфер не заполнился полностью

Как написано выше, по умолчанию потоки связанные с терминалом или линейно-буферизированные или небуферизированные. В первом случае вывод сразу во время `printf()` попадает на экран, а во втором — или сразу, если `printf()` заканчивается новой строкой, или при выполнении `scanf()`. Разницу в поведении можно увидеть на таком примере:

```
printf("Hello ");
sleep(10);
printf("world!\n");
```

На win32 выведется `Hello` и через 10 секунд `world!`, а на *nix — всё сразу через 10 секунд.

> или есть еще моменты когда содержимое из буфера записывается в файл?

Файлы в отличие от терминала обычно полностью буферизированны, например в таком варианте:

```
FILE *f = fopen("foo", "w")
fprintf(f, "Hello world!\n");
getc(stdin);
fclose(f);
```

Во время задержки на `getc()` файл будет пустой.

Кроме случая полного заполнения буфер сбрасывается принудительно при закрытии файла (`fclose()`), корректном завершении программы (`exit()` или `return` из `main()`, но **не** обязательно при `abort()`). Также некоторые другие стандартные функции могут вызывать `fflush()`, например `fseek()` или функции чтения из файла, открытого для чтения/записи, но это уже зависит от реализации.

> К этому так же не могу понять зачем нужен fflash().

`fflush()` собственно нужен, чтобы принудительно записать содержимое буфера в файл. В примере выше, если добавить `fflush()` перед `getc()`, то `"Hello world!"` будет гарантированно записано в файл. Если немного больше придираться к терминам, то по `fflush()` содержимое буфера «*передаётся среде исполнения*», на практике это не означает, что оно гарантированно окажется сохранено на диске т.к. у ОС есть свои средства буфферизации.

Также стоит запомнить, что `fflush()` влияет только на буфер **вывода** он не оказывает **ни какого** эффекта на потоки ввода..

---

<sup>¹ Вообще говоря всё это определено и для потоков ввода, и для потоков вывода, но на практике на поведение потоков ввода это практически ни как не отражается.</sup>

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не подскажите литературу, где можно побольше таких подробных моментов про другие фишки прочитать?

Comment: @Danny, не думаю, что в литературе есть нечто подобное: букварям это не нужно — слишком специфично и реальное поведение сильно зависит от реализации, да и если не задумываться, то всё «просто работает», хотя у Прата типы буферизации вскользь упоминаются в описании `setvbuf()`...  Но это всё написано на основе собственного опыта+man'ов+экспериментов, чтобы проверить догадки+исходников glibc+сверки со стандартом... Могу порекомендовать [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) — не совсем подборка вида «как это работает», а скорее разбор распространённых ошибок, но там много достаточно интересных моментов...

Answer (score 3):

Буфер входа и выхода синхронизирован по-умолчанию. Это значит, что любая последовательность с разных потоков должна быть с сохранённой последовательностью. Например если вы кидаете в буфер *"введите x:"* и нажали *10* , то вывод должен быть точно *"введите x:10"*, а не *"10 введите x:"*.

Если `scanf` запрашивает данные, то он по-умолчанию выводит нажатые буквы и буфер вывода синхронизируется с помощью `fflush` и выводится `введите x:`. Можно отключить вывод на экран вводимые символы, тогда чтобы пользователь понял, что от него что-то хотят, то нужно очистить буфер иначе на экране не будет запроса `введите x:`. Так происходит при запросе пароля например.

Если вывод происходит в файл, то данные записываются в буфер Си, но **не** записываются в буфер операционной системы. При синхронизации буфер Си очищается и записывается в буфер ОС. Так больше шансов, что данные в файл запишутся при крититической ситуации. (электричество/память/процессор)

Comment: какой-то бессвязный набор слов...