# Действие функции fflush()

Tags: php, файлы

Не понимаю, какое действие выполняет функция php fflush(). В следующем примере у неё как будто нет никакого эффекта:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$filename = '../app/files/bar.txt';

$file = fopen($filename, 'r+');
rewind($file);
echo PHP_EOL;

fwrite($file, 'Foo'); //Запись в файл происходит сразу же
readfile($filename);
echo PHP_EOL;

fflush($file); //То есть эта функция не даёт эффекта какой-то форсированной записи
readfile($filename);
echo PHP_EOL;

ftruncate($file, ftell($file));
readfile($filename);
echo PHP_EOL;

fwrite($file, 'Foo');
readfile($filename); //Все изменения в файлах видны сразу же
echo PHP_EOL;

fclose($file);

echo "</pre>";
```

Эксперименты типа

```
echo "Foo";
ob_flush();
fflush();
```

тоже не дают эффекта, то есть в файл не поступают данные системного буфера.

Расскажите, кто знает, чем эта функция вообще может быть полезна.

Answer (score 0):

[`fflush` вызывает](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.3/ext/standard/file.c#L1238) метод соответствующего [streams API](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.3/README.STREAMS#L41) `php_stream_flush`, который должен вести себя аналогично `ANSI stdio` функции, то есть, `fflush` стандартной библиотеки C:

> These (should) behave in the same way as the ANSI stdio functions with similar
> names: fread, fwrite, fprintf, feof, fgetc, fgets, fclose, fflush, fseek, ftell, flock.

`man 3 fflush` по системной библиотеке, в свою очередь отвечает:

> DESCRIPTION
> For  output streams, fflush() forces a write of all user-space buffered
> data for the given output or update stream via the stream's  underlying
> write function.

> NOTES
> Note  that fflush() flushes only the user-space buffers provided by the
> C library.  To ensure that the data is physically stored  on  disk  the
> kernel  buffers  must  be  flushed  too,  for  example, with sync(2) or
> fsync(2).

Этот вызов *требует*, чтобы были отправлены на запись все буферы в пользовательском пространстве (но могут оставаться буферизованными в пространстве ядра операционной системы, а потому `fflush` не гарантирует запись на физические накопители данных).

Тонкий момент именно в том, что системный fwrite *может* быть буферизован системной библиотекой (и отдельно - ядром системы). А может и нет (что, насколько помню, как раз справедливо для операций над файлами - не буферизуются системной библиотекой, только уже ядром). Или к моменту когда вы это проверяете уже запись из буфера была произведена. `fflush` даёт возможность явным образом гарантировать, что запись из локального буфера программы была выполнена.

Дальше надо уходить в тонкости стандартной библиотеки C и стандартов в частностях, не имеющих отношения к PHP. На ruSO наверняка есть более детальные ответы применительно именно к C, [например этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134146/203622). Да и, в сущности, в типичной модели использования PHP: получили http запрос, сгенерировали ответ и завершились - очень редко где fflush или fsync могут потребоваться. Каноничный пример использования `fflush` - это текстовый интерактивный интерфейс, когда вы выводите на консоль вопрос пользователю, а этот текст вместо консоли сначала попадает в буфер и потому не отображается.