# fflush(stdout) Си

Tags: c, unix

У меня есть код, вот фрагмент:

```
printf("choose (y/n)?");
fflush(stdout);
```

Почему без fflush(stdout) не выводится на экран данная строка. Точнее выводится только после того, как я что-то напечатаю. Как я поняла, все дело, в том, что нет окончания строки(\n), но можете пожалуйста объяснить, почему это именно так работает.

Comment: Окончание строки вообще не при чём.

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде как при чём. `\n` заставит сбросить буфер, что и привидёт к отображению строки на экране.

Comment: @EOF, нет, `std::endl` заставит, а `\n` - просто символ.

Comment: @Qwertiy мы ж вроде про Си говорим.

Comment: @EOF, https://ideone.com/gRe5ij - `Standard output is empty`.
А с `fflush` становится нормально: https://ideone.com/IDXDW6 - `qqq 0`.

Comment: Это эффект буферизации `FILE *`. Для файла, соединненого с tty по умолчанию используется line buffering. А также функции ввода смотрят, нет ли в буфере еще не выведенных данных и если они есть, вызывают fflush

Comment: @andreymal, я вообще ожидал, что для настоящего терминала вывод будет без буферизации, а вот если там всякие перенаправления, например, как у ideone, то как раз и начинаются фокусы. Думаю, если ты перевод строки уберёшь, у тебя всё равно выведется сообщение?

Comment: @Qwertiy, там `stdout` перенаправляется в файл, поэтому он может быть полностью буферизированным. Гарантируется, что на терминал вывод будет всегда. На практике, из-за особенностей реализации, это применимо и к плюсам...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, понял, у винды на способ буферизации меньше))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что стандартные поток ввода, указывающий на «интерактивное устройство» (терминал) в большинстве *nix реализаций является *линейно-буферизированным*. Подробнее о типах буферизации я уже писал здесь: [Буферизация данных в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1133936/%d0%91%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%a1/1134146#1134146).

Для линейно-буферизированных потоков кроме конца строки сброс буфера также будет вызываться при его переполнении или чтении из другого линейно-буферизированного потока (чей буфер ввода пуст); так что ожидаемый результат получится и в примере такого рода:

```
printf("choose (y/n)?");
int answer = getchar(); // вывод произойдёт до или во время вызова `getchar()`
```