# время работы программы на c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, циклы, c++11, время

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему этот код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> in;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j;
        cin >> j;
        in.push_back(j);
        if(in[i] != in[i - 1])
        {
            cout << in[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

работает дольше, чем этот:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> out;
    vector<long long> in;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j;
        cin >> j;
        in.push_back(j);
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(in[i] != in[i - 1])
        {
            cout << in[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Ведь по идее должно быть наоборот, потому что в первом коде мы используем только один вектор и один цикл for, а во втором два вектора и два цикла for. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: а как вы измеряли время? если разница небольшая, то скажу я вам, что разница во времени работы довольна интересная величина, которая может варьироваться не только из-за кода самой программы, но и других различных факторов

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, есть подозрение, что этот вопрос поинтереснее и разница там существенная.

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov разница довольна существенная, порядка 250 мс, при том, что занятая память примерно одинакова.

Comment: В обеих случаях вы выходите за пределы вектора при первом сравнении. Компилятор может пропустить это каким то образом, но и для этого время может быть потрачена.  А второй раз он уже понимает, что вы игнорируете ошибку и оптимизацию, и сам может вместо вас это сделать.  Во вторых вы не знаете что делает в это время операционная система, которая работает не зависимо от вашего кода. Так что эта доля секунды  зависит от компилятора и  ОС. Лично у меня на данный момент, с конкретным компилятором получается обратный результат

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Предполагаю, что наблюдаемая вами разница в скорости работы потоков ввода/вывода связана с буферизацией.

Стандартный объект вывода `std::cout` *привязан* к стандартному объекту ввода `std::cin`. Это означает, что перед любой операцией ввода объект `std::cin` вызывает `std::cout.flush()`. Вот что пишет [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout):

> Once initialized, `std::cout` is `tie()`'d to `std::cin` and `std::wcout` is `tie()`'d to `std::wcin`, meaning that any input operation on `std::cin` executes `std::cout.flush()` (via `std::basic_istream::sentry`'s constructor).

В вашем первом примере кода внутренний буфер `std::cout` работает не очень эффективно: только объект `std::cout` положит очередную порцию данных в свой внутренний буфер, как `std::cin` даёт команду опустошить его — отправить содержимое буфера во внешнее окружение.
Во втором примере кода `std::cin` также на каждой итерации цикла пытается опустошить буфер вывода, но так как он пуст (вывод происходит в другом цикле) — это не создаёт проблем с производительностью.

Однако, наверняка утверждать, что имеет место описанное выше поведение **нельзя**. Есть **разные** стратегии буферизации потоков. В своём вопросе вы не указали ни используемую операционную систему, ни используемый компилятор, ни куда/откуда пишите/читаете данные. См.: [Буферизация данных в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1133936).

Если перенаправить стандартные потоки ввода вывода в файлы, то наблюдаемое вами поведение вроде бы не сложно повторить.

Сгенерируем текстовый файл `"1.txt"`, хранящий `20'000'000` целых чисел из отрезка `[0; 9]`. Код генерации:

```
std::ofstream fout("1.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
std::mt19937 mt;

const long data_size = 20'000'000;

char buf[] = {0, ' '};
for (long i = 0; i < data_size; ++i)
{
    buf[0] = "0123456789"[mt() % 10];
    fout.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
}
fout.close();
```

А теперь прочитаем его, записывая некоторые прочитанные числа в другой файл (немного изменённый ваш код):

```
//std::cin.tie(nullptr);
long long num_old = 0;
while (true)
{
    long long num_cur;
    std::cin >> num_cur;
    if (std::cin.fail())
        break;

    if ( num_cur != num_old )
        std::cout << num_cur << '\n';
    num_old = num_cur;
}
```

На моей системе приведённая программа выполнилась за **58** секунд. После отвязывания выходного потока от входного с помощью метода [tie()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie) (раскомментировав строку `std::cin.tie(nullptr);`) программа стала выполняться **24** секунды.

Теперь, оставив потоки связанными, разделим ввод данных и вывод:

```
std::vector <long long> vect;
long long num_old = 0;
while (true)
{
    long long num_cur;
    std::cin >> num_cur;
    if (std::cin.fail())
        break;

    if ( num_cur != num_old )
        vect.push_back(num_cur);
    num_old = num_cur;
}
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << vect[i] << '\n';
```

Данная программа выполнилась на моей системе за **25** секунд.

---

> но почему во втором примере буфер вывода пуст? мы же его наполняем содержимым `in[i]`, точно так же, как и в первом примере

Да, наполняем, но во втором варианте вашего кода наполнение происходит **после** того как все данные считанны. Это означает что `std::cin` **не вмешивается** в работу буфера `std::cout`. (Точнее говоря вмешивается, но на момент вмешательства внутренний буфер `std::cout` пуст.) Таким образом буфер `std::cout` опустошается по мере заполнения, а не принудительно на каждой итерации цикла. На практике опустошение буфера означает обращение к ресурсоёмким функциям ОС, которые отображают содержимое буфера на экране или пишут в файл. И чем реже происходит обращение к этим функциям, тем лучше для производительности.

Ещё один пример:

```
std::ofstream f("out.txt");

for (long i = 0; i < 10'000'000; ++i)
{
    //f.flush(); // <- Раскомментируем данную строку.
    f << '*';
}
```

В приведённом коде на каждой итерации в файловый поток выводится символ `'*'`, но непосредственная запись звёздочек в файл на диск происходит далеко не на каждой итерации цикла. Поток буферизует вывод. Он накапливает символы во вспомогательном внутреннем буфере в оперативной памяти. И только когда буфер заполняется, поток вызывает необходимые функции операционной системы, и происходит запись содержимого внутреннего буфера — сразу множество символов пишутся в файл одной большой группой. Приведённый код у меня работает меньше одной секунды.

Но стоит только добавить принудительное опустошение буфера на каждой итерации цикла: `f.flush();`, как время работы резко возрастает. Теперь на моей системе на генерацию файла понадобилось больше 16 секунд! Вместо того, чтобы писать данные в файл крупными блоками, теперь поток пишет по одному симолу, что занимает уйму времени.

В вашем первом примере кода нет явного вызова `std::cout.flush()`, но есть неявный — на **каждой** итерации цикла в строке `cin >> j;` перед считыванием происходит принудительное опустошение буфера `std::cout`. Если бы буфер был пуст, то проблемы бы не было (т.к. нечего бы было опустошать), но ведь в этом же цикле происходит и наполнение буфера: `cout << in[i] << '\n';`, а значит буфер не пуст, значит потоку приходится обращаться к ресурсоёмким функциям ОС.

Comment: но почему во втором примере буфер вывода пуст? мы же его наполняем содержимым in[i], точно так же, как и в первом примере

Answer (score 5):

Небольшой отчет.

Создал файл из 10000 случайных чисел, на вывод попадают примерно 4500 чисел. При запуске программы передача данных - через перенаправление в командной строке. Вывод на экран. VC++2019, включены все оптимизации, 64 разряда. Три запуска.

Первый вариант - 2238, 2191, 2245 мс на моей машине.
Второй вариант - 2202, 2339, 2161 мс.

Говорить о какой-то разнице не могу...
Просто сам консольный вывод слишком длинный, он забивает все различия. Или вы значения руками вводили? :)

Для сравнения - OpenWatcom на тех же условиях :) в обоих случаях дал по 850 мс.

Но!...
Вот если перенаправлять вывод в файл - да, тогда примерно 36 мс в первом варианте и 16 мс во втором (и по 12 мс в Open Watcom). И вот здесь я могу согласиться с гипотезой Qwertiy.

Но все это, как видим, зависит от конкретного компилятора, так что надо лезть внутрь и смотреть, что там и как... Да, а еще от того, находится ли уже входной файл в дисковом кеше или нет - первые запуски оказывались существенно длиннее.

Кстати, когда в VC++ заменил `cin` и `cout` на `scanf` и `printf` - время в обоих случаях упало до 850 мс, а при выводе в файл - до примерно 9,8 и 9,6 мс. Что еще раз говорит о том, что все несуразицы связаны - по крайней мере в VC++ - с реализацией потоков...

Comment: а что вы имеете ввиду под выводом в файл? что то я не очень понял

Comment: `test.exe < input` - чтение данных из файла и вывод на экран, `test.exe < input > output` - чтение данных из файла, вывод перенаправлен в файл.

Answer (score 4):

Если смешивать ввод и вывод, перед вводом может оказываться flush вывода, который тоже потребует времени. Если в твоём замере этот flush использовался, то в первом случае он вызывался на каждый элемент, а вот втором - только один раз.

Попробуй замерить в перенаправлением вывода в файл и/или в nul - возможно результат изменится по сравнению с консолью.

Comment: но почему в первом случае он вызывался один раз, а во втором несколько раз? в чем отличие?

Comment: @prostak, во-первых, наоборот, а во-вторых, потому что между cin и cout.

Comment: так во втором случае между cin и cout есть цикл for, то есть по идее именно в нем flush должен вызываться несколько раз. или я что то не таки понял?

Comment: @prostak, между, а не перед.

Comment: так я про между и говорю. между ```cin[j]``` и ```cout <<in[i]``` есть цикл for, и по идее этот цикл должен делать так, чтобы flush вызывался несколько раз, разве нет?

Comment: @prostak, что-то я немного не то написал, точнее попутал порядок. Между выводом и вводом, а не между вводом и выводом.