# Бесконечный цикл в c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
  
int main()
{
        int count(0);
        while (count < 10)
        {
                if (count == 5)
                        continue;
                std::cout << count << " ";
                ++count;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Я ожидаю, что программа прежде чем войти в бесконечный цикл выведет `1 2 3 4` , но она этого не делает. У меня сразу начинается цикл. Но если я изменю строчку `std::cout << count << " ";` на
`std::cout << count << " " << std::endl;`, то тогда будет происходить вывод `1 2 3 4` (но в столбик). Вопрос: почему в первом случае числа не выводятся ?

Comment: [Буферизация данных в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1133936)

Comment: Всё в буфере было спрятано. Чтобы показать делайте не `endl` а `..<<std::flush;`

Comment: Также имейте ввиду, что компилятор имеет право (но не обязан)  прерывать бесконечные циклы, которые не производят никаких наблюдаемых эффектов. Т.е. он может `continue` заменить на `break`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe - `endl` у `cout` сбрасывает буфер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `cout` буферизует вывод - писать числа в терминал "дорого" по времени, они попадают во временный буфер. А так как программа зацикливается, они в этом буфере остаются навечно.

`endl` же не только переводит строку, но и заставляет буфер сброситься.

Чтобы сбросить буфер без перевода строки, используйте `cout << flush;`